# Oracle.DataAccess.dll getting copied to Debug\Release bin folders despite Copy Local = false

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, msbuild, odac

I have a .NET solution which contains multiple projects. All the projects which refer the Oracle.DataAccess.dll have set Copy Local = false. However, When I build the solution, the dll always gets copied to bin folder.

I don't want the dll to get copied because I want to use the Oracle.DataAccess dll sitting on the server that the application is running on instead of being packaged with the code.

I am able to achieve this by referencing the Oracle.DataAccess.dll (and setting copy local false) on the core project building the other projects which reference the odac (and all have copy local false), however the core project itself does not make use of the odac directly, so I am referencing it purely to get the build to behave.

So any ideas on why the solution build is behaving this way? I would rather not have an unused reference to odac in my core project purely for build purposes as it might get removed by a well meaning developer doing a cleanup in future :)

Answer (score 1):

Check how you are referencing the Oracle.DataAccess dll.
Instead of browsing to the Oracle Home bin directory, reference from GAC.